# Replace the last character in a string if it's a particular character in a dataframe Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below. If there's a character in the last position is a dot, I want to replace it as a character "K" , not sure how to add the condition in the replace function

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Mix':['572.7.','44.44','99']})

df['Mix'].str.replace('.','K',regex=False)
```

Sample data

[image]

expected result

[image]

Comment: `mask = df['Mix'].str.endswith('.')` and `df['Mix'][ mask  ].str[:-1]` + 'K', to skip last char and add new one because `replace` without regex would replace all dots in text. Eventually it would need `.apply`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regex to match the last character:

```
df['Mix'].str.replace('\.$','K',regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without regex you could use `.str.endswith('.')` or `.str[-1] == '.'` to filter rows which need to replace last char

```
mask = df['Mix'].str.endswith('.')
#mask = (df['Mix'].str[-1] == '.')

df['Mix'][mask] = df['Mix'][mask]....
```

But problem is `replace` - it would replace all dots in text. It would need to use different method - get text without last char `.str[:-1]` and add new char `+ "K"`

```
df['Mix'][mask] = df['Mix'][mask].str[:-1] + 'K'
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Mix':['572.7.','44.44','99']})

mask = df['Mix'].str.endswith('.')
#mask = (df['Mix'].str[-1] == '.')

df['Mix'][mask] = df['Mix'][mask].str[:-1] + 'K'

print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Similar method with `apply()` (also without `regex`)

```
def modify(text):
    if text.endswith('.'):
        text = text[:-1] + 'K'
    return text

df['Mix'] = df['Mix'].apply(modify)
```